# Letting someone add text to a website

Tags: php, javascript, html

I don't even know how to explain this well, so please bear with me. I searched hotscripts.com, googling key words, but I can't find the right wording! Its driving me nuts...

I am a web designer, who doesn't use PHP. I can design some pretty kick-butt sites but I never dabbled in PHP. I designed a site for my customer, but he would like a feature that where he can type some notes and post it on his site, maybe in a side-bar or where-ever.

Is there any such script that I can try to install (try is the keyword - don't know much about it. All I know how to do is create a PHP database and associate a user with it. So if I find a script somewhere that allows my customer to post something using this PHP script, that would be awesome. I don't want his customers posting on it, just him - so I don't think a log-in box would work.

If he uploads a text file, with what he wants to show on his site, I can show him how to do that - but I don't know the coding how to set this up. Even if it doesn't have anything to do with PHP, what is the best way for this?

Sorry its such a long post - now you can see why I have no idea what to search for to seek assistance.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Can't he just edit the page? Like if it is a .html file can't you specify a space with HTML comment tags stating where to put notes? Or would this not work?

Comment: You're looking for a content management system, or CMS.  Look into PHPnuke or similar such things.  Either that, or you could always go with a blog like Wordpress.  It's customizable enough where you can make it look like a regular website.

Comment: You could make this with some PHP and a Database (I could make this type of thing if I wanted to) but it would take some time. I think a CMS is your best choice as GigaWatt has said.

Comment: Nathan... that's a wonderful idea. I never thought about it that way. He can save the document as an HTML file, and I can designate that named file to appear in a certain section of the website! I will see how that works. I will also look into PHPNuke and Wordpress. Thanks GigaWatt! As far as a PHP database goes, I wouldn't know how to start anything like that - to display information from a PHP Database, so thanks Ceejayoz.

Answer (score 0):

Incredibly easy to do.

Here's the code for his part of the form (put this behind some type of user authentication or Apache .htaccess/.htpasswd authentication)

```
<?php

$file = './edit.txt';

if ( isset( $_REQUEST['save'] ) && isset( $_REQUEST['editor'] ) ) {
    // Save the new contents

    $handle = fopen( $file, 'w' );
    fwrite( $handle, $_REQUEST['editor'] );
    fclose($handle);

}

// Open the contents of the file
$handle = fopen( $file, 'r' );
$contents = fread( $handle, filesize($file) );
fclose($handle);

?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="save" value="1" />
<textarea name="editor" id="editor">
<?php echo ( $contents ); ?>
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Then we simply need to include the file within your design.  This is a single line of code, pointing to the same text file.

```
<?php @include_once('/path/to/edit.txt'); ?>
```

One important point to note: Since we are `include()`ing the file, it is possible for someone with ulterior motives to place PHP code into the text editor, save it, and our script will execute it.  Rather that `include()` we might want to instead use:

```
<?php @readfile( '/path/to/edit.txt'); ?>
```

Comment: Does that <?php @include_once('/path/to/edit.txt'); ?> go between head tags? I put the script in a page, I see the save button. I hit SAVE, and I assume its supposed to go on the page with the above coding, but its not showing up. If this works, you are a god!

Comment: Oh wait! I see a mistake I made. Working at it, desperately... I think this will be perfect!

Comment: Hello... Sorry, I can't get it to work. The submit thing is at: bryankollar.com/boilertuneup/html/try.php and the page I think its supposed to appear on is at bryankollar.com/boilertuneup/html/try.html. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One thing right off the bat - PHP is not parsing your try.html page (if you View Source of the page, you'll see the PHP code still there).  Try renaming to try2.php (or something similar) for starters.

Comment: Next, you'll want to change that include() line.  It's looking for the relative path in terms of folders, not in terms of web address.  Since it is housed inside the same folder, you can just use: `include_once('edit.txt');`

Comment: Lastly, PHP will need a file to record the changes to.  Upload a blank text document named edit.txt into the same folder.  In order for it to be writable, you might need to CHMOD to 755 or 777.  Most FTP client software has this feature.  It might be labeled as CHMOD, or Permissions, or something similar.